# Which statistical model should I use? Poisson regression with multilevel?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, poisson-regression, research-design

I have a study like this: firstly, select several counties within the U.S., and then select bunches of stores within each country. Based on the stores that selected within each country, I need to figure out how many stores have product A and B. For example, there are 50 stores in county X, 30 out of the 50 stores have product A, and 20 out of the 50 stores have product B. And then I find out how many people (with certain feature) within county X need product A (N), and how many people (with certain feature) within county X need product B(n). And I want to compare the rate like: 30/N vs 30/n, or maybe (30/50)/N vs (20/50)/n.

Hopefully that I express myself clearly. Is it the Poisson regression or negative binomial regression? And since there are multiple counties involved, each counties might have different situation, such as population, numbers of stores. Does this model also needs to use multilevel modeling? Could any one help me with it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For your question:

Poisson and NB are both count models. The Poisson model is simpler, so, if its assumptions are met, you can use that. If not, then NB is a common alternative. You can decide this based on examination of the results. Personally, I have never seen the assumption that the variance equals the mean satisfied in any count regression, but it must happen sometimes. However, you seem to be modelling rates, not counts. Beta regression may be a better alternative. But how will you adjust for size of county?

And yes, you need multilevel modeling.

But ... I have some other concerns:

- Counties. You write "select several counties".  But counties are very messy to work with. They range in population from 10.5 million (Los Angeles) down to 94 (not 94,000) for Loving County, TX.  How will you pick?  This is a common problem in this sort of analysis. I don't know of a great solution. Census tracts are much more similar in size, but may be too small for your purposes. You  might try congressional districts, which are also roughly similar in size.
- "select bunches of stores within each county"  - again, how? Many small counties will not have "bunches of stores" and some counties (e.g. Loving) may not have any?
- "there are 50 stores in county X, 30 out of the 50 stores have product A, and 20 out of the 50 stores have product B"  Ummm. What about stores that have neither? Or both? Depending on what the products are and what the stores are, you could get almost any results.
- "then I find out how many people (with certain feature) within county X need product A (N), and how many people (with certain feature) within county X need product B(n). "   How will you find this out? It's very hard to get anything like a random sample of people. Then you will have to survey them. And, again, some will need both, some neither. And surveys are plagued by very low response rates. And "need" is a bit problematic too. (The products we actually *need* are pretty few; but we want a lot of things.) And how often? Some things we buy less than once a year (e.g. a refrigerator), other things we buy once a week or more. Some things are seasonal. Etc.

I don't mean to be too harsh or negative, but I think you need to think about the above, and maybe hire a consultant (not me, I've retired).  This is a very complex project.

Comment: re "assumption of equivariance": I don't know this assumption by name. It has the appearance of being a synonym for "homogeneity of variance" or "homoskedasticity", but then again it could be something completely different. Could you please provide some definition?

Comment: @Galen  That's the one I mean.  I will edit my answer. (I forget where I read "equivariance").

Comment: No problem! Thank you for clarifying. I read a fair bit about invariant and equivariant maps from the viewpoint of geometry, especially geometric deep learning. A statement about the variance not changing with respect to the predictor variable would, if either type of geometric map were to be considered here, be an invariant map rather than an equivariant one. Although the prefix "equi-" does mean something like "equal", it is applied in a certain sense within geometry.

Comment: Actually, I meant that the variance = the mean.  (The terminology can get confusing!)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I really appreciate it! I have another question, do I need to conduct power analysis for this kind of study? If so, what sample size should I compute? The number of stores? The number of stores that have product A / B? Or I can collect as much as I can?

Comment: You will need to do a power analysis, but to do that, you have to formulate your hypothesis and figure out what analysis method you will use.  I don't think you're ready for that yet.

Comment: If I do a power analysis, the sample size is for the number of stores that have product A/B?

Comment: The analysis will depend on your hypothesis.

Comment: The hypothesis would be significantly different between rate of product A and rate of product B. The nominator (number of stores that have product A/B) should be more focused on, does it mean, the sample size is the total stores for each county?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147918/discussion-between-newruser-and-peter-flom).